# Do I need to make an object file, or just the final executable?

Tags: c, makefile

Is it important to include a rule for the production of an object file and then a second rule for the executable, or should I add only one rule to create the executable file in a single command?

Example of separate compile + link:

```
foo: foo.o

foo.o: foo.c
```

Single command:

```
foo: foo.c
```

Comment: In a small single-file setup it doesn't matter. In a multi-file setup, you'll want to separate compilation (=object file creation) from linking (executable file creation) so as to make your rebuilds fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single source file, there is little reason to prefer one over the other.

In larger projects, you will link object files from many translation units, and then it becomes necessary to separate the compilation and linking phases (so that many files can be compiled simultaneously, and many need not be compiled at all if they are up to date).

Make has adequate built-in rules to support both styles of build.

Answer (score 0):

It will be faster on the re-build, so it can be important on a big project